# Perl Dancer Testing: No route_exists for ajax routes?

Tags: ajax, perl, routes, dancer

I use the use [Dancer::Plugin::Ajax](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Dancer-1.3121/lib/Dancer/Plugin/Ajax.pm) to define some ajax routes in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) [Dancer](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Dancer-1.3121/).

```
get '/' => sub { 
    template 'index' => $data;
};

ajax '/api/foo' => sub {
    ...
};

ajax '/api/bar' => sub {
    ...
};
```

In my test I would like to test if all the routes do exist:

```
route_exists [GET => '/'], 'a route handler is defined for /';
route_exists [AJAX => '/api/foo'], 'an ajax route handler is defined for /api/foo';
route_exists [AJAX => '/api/bar'], 'an ajax route handler is defined for /api/bar';
```

But unfortunately that does not work. I also tried

```
route_exists [GET => '/api/foo'], 'an ajax route handler is defined for /api/foo';
route_exists [GET => '/api/bar'], 'an ajax route handler is defined for /api/bar';
```

without succes.

Did I miss the right statement in the documentation?

---

**Update after the first answer from** @simbabque:

It nearly works now. 
Unfortunatly **find_route** in **Dancer::App** uses

```
next if $r->has_options && (not $r->validate_options($request));
```

if it would use

```
next if $r->has_options && (not $r->check_options($request));
```

everything would work fine. 
Background is: **validate_options** in **Dancer::Route** only checks the **$_options_aliases**, but the 
required option is '*ajax*' and that is only mentioned in **$_supported_options**.

Ideas how to work around this limitation?
(I will add my solution if this is fixed.)

Comment: The `ajax` handler works by checking the request headers. You will need to fake those in your test. I need to do some investigating on how to do that exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, just a collection of stuff that will help you figure it out.

First, look at https://metacpan.org/source/YANICK/Dancer-1.3121/lib/Dancer/Request.pm#L341. The `is_ajax` method checks if the request has `$self->{x_requested_with} eq "XMLHttpRequest"`.

If you look at https://metacpan.org/source/YANICK/Dancer-1.3121/t/15_plugins/07_ajax_plack_builder.t, which is the test for the Ajax plugin, it will create a fresh HTTP::Request.

My guess is you will need to do that too, in some way. Look at https://metacpan.org/source/YANICK/Dancer-1.3121/lib/Dancer/Test.pm#L107 for `route_exists` and hack your own version of that for ajax requests.

---

Update:

I hacked a little but did not test this at all:

```
*Dancer::Test::ajax_route_exists = sub {
    my ($req, $test_name) = @_;
    my $tb = Test::Builder->new;

    my ($method, $path) = expand_req($req);
    $test_name ||= "a route exists for $method $path";

    $req = Dancer::Request->new_for_request($method => $path, undef, undef, HTTP::Headers->new( 'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'));
    return $tb->ok(defined(Dancer::App->find_route_through_apps($req)), $test_name);
}
```

Might be this works afterwards:

```
Dancer::Test::ajax_route_exists [GET => '/api/foo'], 'an ajax route handler is defined for /api/foo';
```

Comment: I'm in a hurry. Maybe I'll play around later. Also ask in #dancer on irc.perl.org. The folks there will help.

Comment: Hmm. I get 
syntax error at t\002_index_route.t line 29, near "Dancer::Test::ajax_route_exists [".

Comment: As I said I did not test it. Just an idea.